# Connector for the various part of the MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

What type of connector used to connect the various parts Apple MacBook? The connector of which I speak is like this:[image]

This type of connector is used only by Apple or other companies are using? It is their patent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These connectors are not given a particular generic name by Apple beyond just "cable connector". In their service manuals, the cable connectors are differentiated by referring to what they're connecting. For example, here is a quote from one of their service manuals:

> Disconnect the **battery cable connector** from the logic board, taking
>   care to keep the cable connector flat when pulling it out of its mate.
>   Use your thumb on top and a black stick beneath to prevent too much
>   bend in the cable. An alternative is to use your index fingers (and
>   nails) to grab the sides of the connector and pull straight out, level
>   with the board.

**NOTE:** Bold emphasis added by me.

So, these cable connectors are referred to as various names, such as:

- Battery cable connector
- Audio cable connector
- Microphone cable connector

**Often these cables are known as Halogen-free cables and connectors. These cables/connectors are delicate and you must handle them with care to avoid damage.**

Also, since the image in your question isn't labelled, I should point out that there are also various other cables/connectors in a MacBook, such as:

- LVDS cable
- Port hatch flex connector
- Hard drive flex cable

And the list goes on.

Hope this helps and answers your question. If not, feel free to comment and clarify what you were after.